# What is Exported Directive Context in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, custom-directive

I'm new to angular, while learning angular from it's offical docs I didn't get what is a directive context and a exported directive context.

Can anyone please help me out what is it and how it works...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Context" in this case refer to the variables that a directive can access to. For example, ngFor, you have index, first, last -> that's the context defined within the directive and they're "exported" for you to use.

Comment: Is that mean a directive internally manages a bunch of variables in his context and some of them are exported out to our use...

Comment: yes, you can say that, the ngFor let you use first, last and those variables/internal state is reflected by your input/express (ngFor="let a of X" - first/last depends on X)

Answer (score 0):

The official docs shows good what a directive is and how you can using it. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/naavjopgege?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is a Stackblitz example how a directive works.

And [here](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives) is the guideline.

With a directive you have access to its element. Examples are available on the official docs (see link), too.

[image]

Greetings, Flo